# Stripe Checkout PHP, unable to POST token

Tags: php, stripe-payments

So... I've installed composer and the Stripe library locally and pushed it to my server usig FTP, I then deleted that and installed composer and the Stripe library via SSH directly onto my server... but I can't get Stripe to work!!!!

I'm using NO custom coding... I just need Stripe's basic Checkout.

My Form:  (with the proper php require_once('./config.php'); at the top of the page in php tags)

```
<form action="charge.php" method="POST">
   <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
      data-key="<?php echo $stripe['publishable_key']; ?>"
      data-amount="2298"
      data-name="Company Name"
      data-description="Ohio orders will be charged sales tax"
      data-image="icon/apple-icon-76x76.png"
      data-locale="auto"
      data-billing-address="true"
      data-shipping-address="true"
      data-allow-remember-me="false">
   </script>
</form>
```

My config.php:

```
<?php
   require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

   $stripe = array(
      "secret_key"      => "sk_test_COPIED_DIRECTLY_FROM_STRIPE",
      "publishable_key" => "pk_test_COPIED_DIRECTLY_FROM_STRIPE"
   );

   \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);
?>
```

My charge.php:

```
<?php
   require_once('./config.php');

   $token  = $_POST['stripeToken'];
   $email  = $_POST['stripeEmail'];

   $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
      'email' => $email,
      'source'  => $token
   ));

   $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
      'customer' => $customer->id,
      'amount'   => 2298,
      'currency' => 'usd',
      'description' => 'Example description'
   ));

  echo '<h1>Successfully charged $22.98!</h1>';
?>
```

with all of the above code, I can CLEARY see everything sent to my Stripe dashboard; however, I get the following 402 error "Fatal error: Uncaught Stripe\Error\Card: Cannot charge a customer that has no active card in...."

The Stripe Dashboard tells me:

```
{
   "error": {
   "message": "Cannot charge a customer that has no active card",
   "type": "card_error",
   "param": "card",
   "code": "missing"
   }
}
```

If I try to change my charge.php page to echo $token right after the POST parameter and not $charge anything, I get a completely blank charge.php page with no $token echo'ed....?

Am I not getting a $token back from Stripe?

Comment: "If I try to change my charge.php page to echo $token right after the POST parameter and not $charge anything, I get a completely blank charge.php page", 

Try adding `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); error_reporting(E_ALL);` --- does it return any error detail? What about a backend script that only has `<?php print_r($_POST); ?>` do you get any POST details --- from Stripe checkout? What about from a form of your own design, with a plain <input>

Comment: When I use    <?php print_r($_POST); ?>    I get "Array()"   and that is it,

Comment: I'm not sure where to insert the E_ALL error code into my code

Comment: May be you have faced any issue during getting `token` from Stripe. So try to see any occur in javascript side in your Form page. Otherwise your code is okay